# Adding Mobile-friendly Meta Tags to the javascript output in the Processing IDE

Tags: mobile, processing, processing.js, processing-ide

I'm trying to make my processing app a little more mobile-friendly, which isn't too difficult with these meta tags that I've found.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

However, these require copying into the `<head>` of the generated webpage that the Processing IDE spits out. Every. Single. Time.

Is there an easier way to do this that I'm just not seeing? I looked into the @pjs directives but found nothing. I'm worried I might have to resort to adding the metatags with jquery after the sketch loads.

Comment: processing.js does not generate pages, it's just a JS library for converting .pde source code ot native javascript. Do you mean the JS mode in the Processing IDE? because those are two very different things.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the Processing IDE for development. Edited the question for clarity. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All I had to do was use a custom html template (Javascript > Start Custom Template) and add it there. Simple.